# C# Fortify Security Scan Open Redirect Critical Issue

Tags: c#, fortify

Using C#, how would I fix a Fortify Security Scan Open Redirect Issue on the following line of code?

```
Response.Redirect("mywebsite.aspx" + updatedQueryString);
```

My code looks like this:

```
var idValues = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Request.QueryString.ToString());
idValues.Set("id", id.ToString());
string updatedQueryString = "?" + idValues.ToString();
Response.Redirect("mywebsite.aspx" + updatedQueryString);
```

Comment: possibly changing the code to this 
`Response.Redirect("~/mywebsite.aspx" + updatedQueryString);` || 
Response.Redirect("mywebsite.aspx?" + updatedQueryString); and changing the code to this 
`tring updatedQueryString =idValues.ToString();`